# How do I tell colcon to tell cmake to tell make --jobs?

Tags: ros, colcon, cmake, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's something that saturates all 12 of my available cores:

```
colcon build --parallel-workers=3
```

How do I tell `colcon build` to use at most three cores at any given time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374508/how-do-i-tell-colcon-to-tell-cmake-to-tell-make---jobs?/) by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 193 on 2021-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Colcon doesn't do that. Or, rather, it does, but only in ways that sacrifice one of the two "independent dimensions of parallelization".

Here's the first way:

```
MAKEFLAGS=-j1 colcon build --parallel-workers=3
```

Here's the second way:

```
MAKEFLAGS=-j3 colcon build --executor sequential
```

---

Originally posted by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) with karma: 193 on 2021-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0